# When looking for a maximum safe temperature for a CPU where do I find the Power (W)?

Tags: temperature, speedfan

I'm using [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) to alert me about unsafe CPU temperatures,

```
Found ACPI temperature
Found Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU P7350 @ 2.00GHz
End of detection
```

I looked up my CPU [over at Intel](http://download.intel.com/design/processor/datashts/318732.pdf) and on page 80, there are a list of Power (W) for which the temperature is the maximum.

To select the correct temperature for my alarm to go off (considering there's a range in the table of about 29 degrees), I need to select the correct Power (W) for my laptop.

And of course I would be selecting a temperature a few degrees lower than the one I select from the chart.

How do I determine the correct Power (W) for my Laptop?

Answer (score 1):

You can't "set" the wattage that your processor consumes. Watts are defined as an amount of power consumed in a second, which can vary greatly in any given second or fraction thereof depending on a number of factors including power profile, resource demand, etc.

The spec sheet for your processor specifies its TDP as 25W, so you can reasonably expect it to operate below that at all times. Given the chart you quoted, it is reasonable to assume your maximum "safe" temperature is around 56.5*C, so you should set your alarm somewhere before that.

Comment: I wasn't looking to "set" it I was looking to find out what it was...hmm I wonder if I wrote that..oh I wrote select...okay well I meant select in the context of "selecting a value from the table" within the Intel Datasheet.  But thank you that is what I had in mind.  So in summary you look for the processors Thermal Design Power (TDP) and apply that to the table.

Comment: "PDF Page" 78 of the datasheet has W / TDP listed as 65.0, which column are you pulling your W number 25W from?

Comment: http://ark.intel.com/products/36750/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-P7350

Comment: You're reading the TDP for an E7300, which I understand may seem close enough to your own processor, but there is actually a significant difference between that one and your own P7350.